# Compile Error: Expected function or variable in VBA for access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I know near nothing about VBA, but I'm trying to modify an application to connect to a MySQL Database.

The following code produces a Compile error at `rstProjets.Open` and I can't seem to find why.

```
Public mysqlConn As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim rstProjets As ADODB.Recordset
ConnectMySQL
Set rstProjets = rstProjets.Open("SELECT * FROM subventions LIMIT 5", mysqlConn)
With rstProjets
    If Not .EOF And Not .BOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
        MsgBox "Subventions:" & rstProjets![pin], , "Subvention ajoutée"
        .MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox "Aucune données à mettre à jour !", , "LVMB"
    End If 
    .Close
End With
mysqlConn.Close
End Sub

Private Sub ConnectMySQL()
Set mysqlConn = New ADODB.Connection
mysqlConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=127.0.0.1;" & _
    "DATABASE=database;" & _
    "USER=root;" & _
    "PASSWORD=;" & _
    "Option=0"
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be useful to know _where_ and _what_ compile error :)

Comment: When I click on a button, it triggers this sub and all I get is this message: Compile Error: Expected function or variable

Comment: Run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  When that triggers a compile error, it will highlight something in the code.  What is highlighted when you get that compile error?

Comment: A compile error should be highlighting the line on which the compiler fails the compilation. Could you please tell us which line is it? (Most probably, it's `ConnectMySQL` (third line of code), which is a macro coming from somewhere else that you didn't include into your project).

Comment: The very first line is highlighted: Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(). ConnectMySQL is properly included. If I remove the code inside the sub and replace it with a MsgBox, then there is no compile error.

Comment: I edited my question with the remaining relevant code.

Comment: The very first line is highlighted yellow after you click on "OK" of the error message. The highlighting I'm talking about is the blue one, before you close the error window. Do you get it ?

Comment: After I pressed F5, .Open got highlighted in blue

Comment: You are using ADO, so your 'open' syntax is not good...  try rstProjets.Open ...., mysqlConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Comment: Can you tell me how it should be?

Comment: The open method does not return a recordset, it's a procedure that you're trying to assign to a variable; that's why you get the error. See the answer below, it should work.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your *rstProjets* object variable to a `New ADODB.Recordset`, and then call its `.Open` method.

```vb
Dim rstProjets As ADODB.Recordset
ConnectMySQL
Set rstProjets = New ADODB.Recordset
rstProjets.Open "SELECT * FROM subventions LIMIT 5", mysqlConn
```