# VBA - Why do I get a compile error expected function or variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am curious to understand why the following throws and compile error stating it is expecting a function or variable

```
Dim frm as Form
set frm = DoCmd.OpenForm(FormName:=mstr_FORM_NAME, View:=acDesign, WindowMode:=acHidden)
```

but I can do this

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:=mstr_FORM_NAME, View:=acDesign, WindowMode:=acHidden
set frm=Forms(mstr_FORM_NAME)
```

I have no issue with doing what works, I just want to understand what is going on with the former statement.

Thank you,
Fred

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile Error: Expected function or variable in VBA for access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28816518/compile-error-expected-function-or-variable-in-vba-for-access)

Comment: Ken, I read the referenced post before I posted here but the post did not seem to address answer my question or confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoCmd.OpenForm` is a method which doesn't return a value. In the second code snippet you are accessing the `Forms` Collection, which contains the form, after it has been opened by DoCmd.OpenForm. When you call a method, you must not specify braces.

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense. I guess I just didn't understand well enough the idea of a method not returning a value. Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2):

The `OpenForm` method ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) is not returning anything, just opening the form (not returning it).

So, you're trying to cast `Nothing` into a variable defined `As Form`.
Instead, `frm` (having the `Set frm =` statement) is expecting to "become something", *it is expecting a function or variable* - a value, to be clear).